# How to add silence in front of a wav file

Tags: python, audio, wav

I am new to python. I am working on an experiment which make use of audio (WAV) files. And I have more than 100 audio file with variable lengths. Which the longest one is 10 seconds. But for my experiment I need all files to have the same length which is 10 seconds. So I want to add few seconds of silence in front to these files with length of less than 10 seconds.

So how can I add silence to the beginning of a WAV file with python? with variable length of silence

Comment: I'd have thought it was better to put the silence on the end, otherwise the listener has to put up with an unknown period of silence before being surprised by the actual sound. Whatever, you could try to do this by creating/playing a WAV file which has enough samples at whatever sample rate you are using to last for (10-L) seconds, where L is the duration of the actual audio file. What have you tried? PS there is a Python Standard Library package called _wave_ which you might be interested in. I found it by searching for: python wav audio. Have you tried searching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a small script which allows you to prepend your signal with a silence in order to obtain the target duration in seconds. It uses the scipy function for reading of the wav file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function, division
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavf
import numpy as np
from sys import argv

def pad_audio(data, fs, T):
    # Calculate target number of samples
    N_tar = int(fs * T)
    # Calculate number of zero samples to append
    shape = data.shape
    # Create the target shape    
    N_pad = N_tar - shape[0]
    print("Padding with %s seconds of silence" % str(N_pad/fs) )
    shape = (N_pad,) + shape[1:]
    # Stack only if there is something to append    
    if shape[0] > 0:                
        if len(shape) > 1:
            return np.vstack((np.zeros(shape),
                              data))
        else:
            return np.hstack((np.zeros(shape),
                              data))
    else:
        return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(argv) != 4:
        print("Wrong arguments.")
        print("Use: %s in.wav out.wav target_time_s" % argv[0])
    else:
        in_wav = argv[1]
        out_wav = argv[2]
        T = float(argv[3])        
        # Read the wav file
        fs, in_data = wavf.read(in_wav)
        # Prepend with zeros
        out_data = pad_audio(in_data, fs, T)
        # Save the output file
        wavf.write(out_wav, fs, out_data)
```

Comment: what is the variable T?

Comment: As described: `target_time_s`. In your case it is 10 seconds.

Comment: I run your code and I get the following error message when using vstack. "valueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly". I think it is because the dimension of the zero paddings and the data are different. But i can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: The code runs fine now. But the audio quality is degraded too much. You can't even here a word purely. Do you have something to say about that?

Comment: I have no idea since we don't have any of your signals. With my signals it's no different, just digital zeros in the beginning.

Comment: How would you edit this to append to the back of the file?

Comment: Just swap the order of zeros and data inside of tuples (*stack functions).

Comment: replacing np.zeros(shape) with np.zeros(shape, data.dtype) fixed the quality degradation. @Same

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append the silence at the end, this is really simple with [PySoundFile](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.org/).

Just [open the file](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.org/#soundfile.SoundFile) in `'r+'` mode, use [seek(0, sf.SEEK_END)](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.org/#soundfile.SoundFile.seek) to move to the end of the file and use [write()](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.org/#soundfile.SoundFile.write) to write the necessary number of zero-frames.
In the end, don't forget to [close()](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.org/#soundfile.SoundFile.close) the file (or use [SoundFile](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.org/#soundfile.SoundFile) as a context manager).

This changes the files in-place.

If you want to add the silence in the beginning, you'll have to copy the existing content as @jojek showed (but you can still use PySoundFile for this, if you want).

Answer (score 0):

As noted in @Same's comments, both of these methods resulted in a huge quality degradation for me. Instead, I ultimately ended up using the [pysox](https://github.com/rabitt/pysox) package to solve my problem (for me, I was prepending a set duration, but you could extend this answer around the use case above). Note that better documentation can be found at https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pysox/latest/pysox.pdf.

```
import sox
tfm = sox.Transformer()
tfm.pad(start_duration=prepend_duration)
tfm.build(in_wav, out_wav)
```